# How do I modify one activity's variables from another activity?

Tags: android, variables, android-intent, android-activity, storage

Let's say
First.class
has a variable
String currentValue = "Red"
with a button that leads to Second.class (an activity). First.class(Activity) displays in a textview what the variable currentValue happens to be. (Currently, Red).

If we push the button, it takes us to Second.class, which has an EditText box to modify the variable in First.class. It also has a button to confirm the change. Finally, it has a TextView at the very bottom showing a preview of what First.class' value variable is.

When a user types in "Blue" in Second.class' EditText box and hits the button, how would we change the variable from First.class without using intents and going back to that activity? I want to stay within Second.activity and do the changes from there.

After hitting the confirm button, the preview TextView should update to match the newly modified variable. We should still be seeing Second.class, I remind you. If the user hits "Back" or "up" at this point, they should return to First.class and also see that the TextView in First.class has been changed.

**How do I modify First.class' variables if Second.class is entirely separate from First.class and cannot access it? (First.class is the hierarchical parent of Second.class.**

Comment: Why don't you want to use `Intent`? This is exactly what it is for. Using `startActivityForResult()` in first `Activity` and `setResult()` in second `Activity`.

Comment: Depending on what you mean by " hierarchical parent", if second is a subclass of first then you can use a member variable in first then second should have access to it.

Comment: Second.class is not a subclass of First.class. Also, I didn't want to use Intent because I was worried that if I called startActivity, it would send the user back to the First.class layout, which I don't want. I'll take a look at startActivityForResult() and setResult() though, and get back to you.

Comment: Ok, I really think `startActivityForResult()` will work for you but if not then consider `SharedPreferences` as Squonk has mentioned in that answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How do I modify First.class' variables if Second.class is entirely separate from First.class and cannot access it?

You can't or (more importantly) you should not try to do this.

The Android `Activity` is a "special case" class and should be generally considered as being self-contained. In other words any changes to data in the second `Activity` which need to be reflected in the first `Activity` must be either persisted using some form of global storage (`SharedPreferences` for example) or should be passed using the extras of an `Intent` or a `Bundle`.

With `SharedPreferences` simply have the first `Activity` save your `currentValue` before starting the second `Activity` and do the reverse in second `Activity` before returning to the first. The first `Activity` then simply needs to check the `SharedPreferences` in `onResume()` and update its `TextView` if necessary.

As codeMagic mentioned, however, simply using `startActivityForResult(...)` would allow passing `currentValue` from the first to the second `Activity` and, before the second exits, updating the `Bundle` with any changes will allow it to be passed back to the first `Activity` through `onActivityResult(...)`.

Comment: Wasn't even thinking about `SharedPreferences` because `Intent` seems so obvious here...good point!

Comment: I think I'll be going with SharedPreferences. The reason being is, I'm actually trying to modify variables from an object, not just some primitive string. If I am to have First.class store an object which contains modifiable variables, how do I save them in SharedPreferences? SharedPreferences only stores primitives, doesn't it?

Comment: I think I found the answer. It's a simple file and object i/o stream. I think I can try figuring out the rest from here. SharedPrefs was a very good thing for me to study though--I'll use it for primitive data should it come to it. :)

Comment: @TonyN.Tran : If you need to do something more complex than `SharedPreferences` or passing a `Bundle` can cope with then you should consider using a helper class (standard Java POJO) which can hold anything you need and, if you design it as a singleton, there will only ever be one instance of it and it can be accessed by any of your application components.

Comment: I see. Would you recommend doing that as opposed to setting up a tedious i/o stream? It sounds way easier than what I'm currently doing.